# Error when concatenating the local variable

Tags: tensorflow

I try to make a custom layer. Everything work ok in Eager mode and successfully compiled. But when I try to fit my model I've got the next error: I recognized that the reason is self.total variable, when I try to concatenate it with calculated tensor. If I remover loop I can't process inputs which has more then 1 value. Maybe there is another way to get the right result without errors Thx

```
def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):

    for i in tf.range(0, tf.shape(inputs)[0]):
        self.total = tf.concat([self.total, tf.reshape(self.concat_result(inputs[i]), [1, 3])], 0)

    return self.total

def __init__(self):
    super(ConcatLayer, self).__init__(dtype=tf.float64)
    self.total = tf.Variable((np.empty((0, 3), dtype=np.float64)), shape=[None, 3])
```

error:

```
TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed
a "Graph" tensor. It is possible to have Graph tensors
leak out of the function building context by including a
tf.init_scope in your function building code.
For example, the following function will fail:      
  @tf.function
  def has_init_scope():
    my_constant = tf.constant(1.)
    with tf.init_scope():
      added = my_constant * 2
The graph tensor has name: while:3
```

Comment: What happens in concat_result() ?  pls post more code/

Comment: it's doesn't matter. it is working ok if I remove the loop and not collect result to self. total